# Showing image OpenCV in Raspberry Pi 4 is slow

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi4

Show image in Raspberry pi 4 with OpenCV takes a lot of CPU resources, is there any way to employ GPU resource to speed it up

Comment: You can try imshow with gpu_Mat.

Comment: Have you asked on [Raspberry Pi stack](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Please show your code, and a representative image and information as to how you determined it takes lots of resources. Thank you.